# Misplaced construct in homework

Tags: java, construct

I do all my programming assignments in eclipse first before putting them in putty and submitting them to our teacher. In eclipse, I have this strange error in one of my methods.

it says "Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)."

```
public static int factorial(int iVal, boolean DEBUG)
{
 int result;
    // Defensive programming
 if(iVal <= 0)
 {
  System.out.println("Error: iVal cannot be a negative number!");
  System.exit(0);
 }
    // Calculate result
 int factor = iVal;
 int counter = iVal - 1;
 for(int i = counter; i > 1; i--)
 {
  if(DEBUG = true)
  {
   System.out.println("DEBUG");
    System.out.println("   Finding the factorial of " + factor);
   System.out.println("   Currently working on " + i);
   System.out.println("   With an intermediate result of" + iVal);
  }
  iVal *= i;
 }
       result = iVal;
    // Return result
       return result;
} // End of factorial method
```

---

It has the error placed on the line consisting of

```
System.out.println("   Currently working on " + i);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: This code compiles fine. Give the whole class.

Comment: What happens if you run the file although it gives you the error?

Answer (score 4):

```
if(DEBUG = true)
```

Comparison is `==`, assignment is `=`.
Also, if you are just testing a boolean value, you don't need to do a comparison at all and just use

```
if(DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an assignment in an if statement:

if(DEBUG = true){

This is legal (and compiles) because `DEBUG` is of type `boolean`, but it is always `true`.